# Re matching all the text between two occurences of a word

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file whose contents follows a set of rules. Here is a snippet of the file:

```
<class 'NXOpen.Features.FeatureCollection'>
Type: <class 'NXOpen.Features.DatumCsys'> FeatureName: Datum Coordinate System(0)
    Parents:
    Children:
        Name:  , JournalIdentifier: SKETCH(1:1B)
    Expressions:
    Entities:
        Name:  , JournalIdentifier: HANDLE R-849
        Name:  , JournalIdentifier: HANDLE R-850
        Name:  , JournalIdentifier: DATUM_CSYS(0) YZ plane
        Name:  , JournalIdentifier: DATUM_CSYS(0) XZ plane
        Name:  , JournalIdentifier: DATUM_CSYS(0) XY plane
        Name:  , JournalIdentifier: DATUM_CSYS(0) X axis
        Name:  , JournalIdentifier: DATUM_CSYS(0) Y axis
        Name:  , JournalIdentifier: DATUM_CSYS(0) Z axis
Type: <class 'NXOpen.Features.DatumCsys'> FeatureName: Datum Coordinate System(1)inf
    Parents:
        Name:  , JournalIdentifier: DATUM_CSYS(0)
    Children:
        Name:  , JournalIdentifier: SKETCH(1)
    Expressions:
    Entities:
        Name:  , JournalIdentifier: HANDLE R-4283
        Name:  , JournalIdentifier: HANDLE R-4284
        Name:  , JournalIdentifier: SKETCH(1:1B) YZ plane
        Name:  , JournalIdentifier: SKETCH(1:1B) XZ plane
        Name:  , JournalIdentifier: SKETCH(1:1B) XY plane
        Name:  , JournalIdentifier: SKETCH(1:1B) X axis
        Name:  , JournalIdentifier: SKETCH(1:1B) Y axis
        Name:  , JournalIdentifier: SKETCH(1:1B) Z axis
```

I want to use `re` to then extract all the text between two **Type:** tags, for example, I want to extract this:

```
Type: <class 'NXOpen.Features.DatumCsys'> FeatureName: Datum Coordinate System(0)
    Parents:
    Children:
        Name:  , JournalIdentifier: SKETCH(1:1B)
    Expressions:
    Entities:
        Name:  , JournalIdentifier: HANDLE R-849
        Name:  , JournalIdentifier: HANDLE R-850
        Name:  , JournalIdentifier: DATUM_CSYS(0) YZ plane
        Name:  , JournalIdentifier: DATUM_CSYS(0) XZ plane
        Name:  , JournalIdentifier: DATUM_CSYS(0) XY plane
        Name:  , JournalIdentifier: DATUM_CSYS(0) X axis
        Name:  , JournalIdentifier: DATUM_CSYS(0) Y axis
        Name:  , JournalIdentifier: DATUM_CSYS(0) Z axis
```

and this

```
Type: <class 'NXOpen.Features.DatumCsys'> FeatureName: Datum Coordinate System(1)inf
    Parents:
        Name:  , JournalIdentifier: DATUM_CSYS(0)
    Children:
        Name:  , JournalIdentifier: SKETCH(1)
    Expressions:
    Entities:
        Name:  , JournalIdentifier: HANDLE R-4283
        Name:  , JournalIdentifier: HANDLE R-4284
        Name:  , JournalIdentifier: SKETCH(1:1B) YZ plane
        Name:  , JournalIdentifier: SKETCH(1:1B) XZ plane
        Name:  , JournalIdentifier: SKETCH(1:1B) XY plane
        Name:  , JournalIdentifier: SKETCH(1:1B) X axis
        Name:  , JournalIdentifier: SKETCH(1:1B) Y axis
        Name:  , JournalIdentifier: SKETCH(1:1B) Z axis
```

using regular expressions. I have been trying this in [python](/questions/tagged/python):

```
re.findall('Type: [\w\s]+)Type:', string)
```

but this gives me an empty list. What should be the correct `re` expression to achieve this?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your pattern `Type: [\w\s]+)Type:` there is an unclosed `)`

The problem with matching `Type:` 2 times in the pattern, is that the second time you match it in the pattern, it will prevent the next match starting with Type: as it is already matched.

---

You can use a pattern to match Type: followed by all lines that do not start with it.

```
^Type: .*(?:\n(?!Type: ).*)*
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `Type:`  Match literally
- `.*` Match the rest of the line
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\n(?!Type: ).*` Match a newline and assert that it does not start with `Type:` , then match the whole line
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeta

Using re.findall the line would be

```
re.findall(r"^Type: .*(?:\n(?!Type: ).*)*", string, re.M)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iBRJ0z/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/fd1cVn)

Comment: Thank you very much. I am new at regex, can you tell me what the ?: does?

Comment: @AmanSavaria That is a non capture group `(?:` I have added a breakdown of the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```py
"(?ms)^Type:(?:(?!^Type:).)*"
```

Where `(?ms)` turns on `re.MULTILINE` and `re.DOTALL` modes so `^` matches the start of each line and `.` matches any character including newlines.

Comment: This only matches the first one, there are multiple occurrences of what I want to match in the file.

Comment: @AmanSavaria No, it will match them all. Have you actually tried it?

Comment: Yes it does, Im sorry it was my mistake.